# Get a var from the current page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

### How can i get a variable with chrome extension from the sourcecode of the current page?

The JS path is `document.querySelector("#sidebar-nav > ul > li.nav-header.nav-header-first > script")`

So is it possible to do something like this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("#sidebar-nav > ul > li.nav-header.nav-header-first > script");
var enry = elem.getVarbyName('energy_time').value;
console.log(enry); // should be 35
```

---

The source code looks like this:

[image: source code]

Comment: Use a regexp on textContent to extract the value. Is using regexp the actual problem or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have do it with indexof and substring but i am sure it is also possible with regexp like @wOxxom said. i dont know regexp rules well so i do it like this:

```
var contentscript = document.querySelector("#sidebar-nav > ul > li.nav-header.nav-header-first > script").innerText;
var enry = contentscript.substring(contentscript.indexOf("var energy_time = ")+18,contentscript.indexOf("var energy_restore =")-38);
console.log(enry); // result is 35
```